# Display long text using Div tag with out stripping whitespace

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display the following text.
In Controller:

```
var message = 'Original Message:'+'\n'+'\n'+'From:CustomerService'+'\n'+'createdDate:2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00';
```

In HTML:

```
<div style="word-wrap:break-word"">{{message}}
</div>
```

But I am getting the message like this:

> OriginalMessage:From:CustomerServicecreateDate:2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00

The div tag is ignoring new line and white space characters .

Answer (score 1):

Your encoding `\n` doesn't mean new line for html in HTML you use **`<br>`** instead.

```
$scope.message = 'Original Message: <br>' + 
   'From:CustomerService'+'<br>'+'createdDate:2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00';
```

Since you are using angular you may want to check  `ng-bind-html` attribute.

Here is a [**full demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FUiasZudjU1jjDPfQ3lv?p=preview)

**JS**

```
 $scope.message = 'Original Message: <br>' + 
       'From:CustomerService'+'<br>'+'createdDate:2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00';
```

**HTML**

```
<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
```

Comment: I just gave a sample but actually the message is coming from back end and they are sending encoded data using base64 and I am using atob(message) function to decode. when I check in console the method is  decoding including new line and white spaces but in div tag it is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have text with `\n` that you want to display in html you can use
`white-space: pre-wrap;`

If you don't need it as text us `<br>` for html line breaks. You can also parse the text and replace `\n` with `<br>` before rendering if that is preferred

```js
var message = 'Original Message:'+'\n'+'\n'+'From:CustomerService'+'\n'+'createdDate:2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00';
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = message
```

```css
#content {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```